# How to highlight a item in recyclerview in android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How can we simply highlight an item in a RecyclerView whenever we click on an item?
Item should be highlighted only for the moment when it is clicked

Answer (score 0):

You can create a selector and use it as a background for each row of your RecyclerView in its adapter.

Comment: I did it as follows:                                                                                     <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_activated="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/colorAccent" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>

Comment: change it to :
<selector xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">; <item android:state_activated="false" android:color="@android:color/transparent" /> <item android:state_activated="true" android:color="@color/colorAccent" /> <item android:color="@android:color/transparent" /> </selector>

Answer (score 0):

Create a drawable like this as **res/drawable/item_bg.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:color="@color/color_when_pressed"/>
 <item android:state_pressed="false"
      android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
```

And set this in your custom itemView Layout parent layout

```
android:background="@drawable/item_bg"
```